# Exploding checkbox values into two separate strings

Tags: php, forms, email

I have form that pulls an array based on the locations that are selected in the form. This selection needs to do two things. It needs to send the location name to the recipient and pull a different email for each location to send to. My problem is you need to be allowed to select multiple locations. I can get the email to change based on what they select but not if there are more than one email.

My form looked like this but I was not able to get the email to send to multiple email addresses.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="location[]" value="location1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="location[]" value="location2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="location[]" value="location3" />

<?php
$location = implode(", ",$_POST['location']);  
?>
```

So I am trying to explode and separate these two get two strings "location1, location2, location3" and "email1, email2, email3" There are 30 locations all with different emails. Now I have it set up like this.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="location[]" value="location1:email1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="location[]" value="location2:email2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="location[]" value="location3:email3" />

<?php
$location = explode(":",$_POST['location']);  
$location2 = implode(", ",'$location[1]');  
?>
```

Ok so after the comments below I am now looking at:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="location[location1]" value="email1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="location[location2]" value="email2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="location[location3]" value="email3" />

$array = $_POST['location'];
foreach($array as $location => $email) {
echo $location;  // will write location1, location2, and location3
echo $email; // will write email1, email2, and email3
```

}

Array looks like this when print_r($_POST);

```
Array
(
[otherinfo] => asdf
[g-recaptcha-response] => 
[fullname] => asdf
[email] => adsf
[phone] => asdf
[address] => asdf
[city] => asdf
[state] => asdf
[zipcode] => asfd
[workedbefore] => yes
[typedesired] => part-time
[license] => yes
[licensetype] => asdf
[location] => Array
    (
        [0] => email1, email2
    )

[select_position] => stylist
[companyname] => asdf
[companyaddress] => adsf
[companycity] => asdf
[companystate] => asdf
[positions] => adsf
[responsibilities] => asdf
[startdate] => 2016-06-07
[enddate] => 2016-06-17
[startingpay] => asdf
[endingpay] => afsd
)
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Have you tried `name="location[location1]" value="email@domain.com"`? Is that feasible or is the key then too long?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to create a table in your database of `Location and EmailAddress` and then you only need the one item of data i.e. `Location` Should the email for a location chnage it would also make that change very much easier

Comment: @Rasclatt how would I separate that into two separate strings? I could get the emails to work that way but am not familiar with pulling data from the name like that.

Comment: Well it's just the key so if you do a foreach loop on location array you get the key.

Comment: @rasclatt I updated the post with where I am at but am still having problems. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I would like to do what you are suggesting, but I have no idea how. Do you have an links to resources on how to do that?

Comment: Just add a `print_r($_POST);` to the top of your script. Then run it with some data and look at what the $_POST array actually looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *@RiggsFolly* mentioned, the better way to do it would be to match up the location based on email or vice versa from your database, but if you want to attempt what I suggest:

This set of inputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="location[location1]" value="email1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="location[location2]" value="email2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="location[location3]" value="email3" />
```

Would give you:

```
Array
(
    [location] => stdClass Object
        (
            [location1] => email1
            [location2] => email2
            [location3] => email3
        )
)
```

So:

```
$array = $_POST['location'];
foreach($array as $location => $email) {
    echo $location;  // will write location1, location2, and location3
    echo $email; // will write email1, email2, and email3
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I am still getting $location as "0" and not the values in the key.

Comment: Edit your question using `print_r($_POST)` after you submit the form, then I can see what you are actually working with.

Comment: I updated the question. It appears that it is not pulling the location at all.

Comment: Well, that `$_POST` array does not look right. It should appear like mine does if you have it laid out the same. That is a raw `$_POST` from the form submit?

Comment: I updated it with the whole array that comes with all of the fields I currently have in there. Does this help solve the problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't help because your server seems to not be able separate out the array name, so that is strange. I've never seen that before. It would normally look like the array I posted, so to see it all in one key (`0`) with commas is really strange. How do you populate those inputs? From a database?

Comment: Oh wow... So i figured out why it is doing that.. The form it is created on is a multipage form. I lost the key by the time it hit the end of the form. If I put your code on page2 of the form I can get it to show up. The array shows up correct if I push the first page to my mail.php file and print_r($_POST) I guess the question is now, how can I get it to pull that array through the form?

Comment: I almost got it! but now the array is working but when I try and put it into the email and add $location to the email it is only pulling one of the values from the array. It does the same with $email.

Comment: Again, unfortunately I can't help you because I can not see your script or what it outputs at what point, etc. It's impossible to guess without seeing what you have.